# Need Help with token Program 2022 - solana

Tags: solana-program, spl-token, solana-cli

I want a token with token program 2022 where I need a tax fee for transfer and want whitelist mechanism to whitelist wallets so the white listed wallets will not pay tax fee. Please guide me if it is achieveable with the solana cli.I read the Docs and I haven't found any solution.
docs:
https://spl.solana.com/token-2022

Comment: You may need to create your own Transfer Hook program to implement the custom functionality required for your use case. https://spl.solana.com/token-2022/extensions#transfer-hook

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can definitely do this with token-2022 using just the transfer fee.

If you want to whitelist certain accounts to not pay the transfer fee, it might be easier to refund the transfer funds back to those accounts, which will make your implementation much simpler.

When you run the job to collect transfer fees, you also look at all transactions involving your whitelisted accounts, see how much they lost to transfer fees, and credit them back to those accounts.

Comment: How exactly I can do that? can you share a video? doc link?

Comment: You can read about how to configure a transfer fee on your mint at https://spl.solana.com/token-2022/extensions#transfer-fees

Comment: Thank you so much I have completed the Token With Custom RUST Program and With anchor.

Comment: Please accept the answer if it helped so that others may find it in the future

Comment: thank you so much! your answer is exactly for those who want to do it with the spl-token-cli